# Validating deep links on web app hosting on Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, jekyll, create-react-app, github-pages, android-deep-link

I have a `create-react-app` application hosted on GitHub pages, with a custom domain `www.example.com`.

I need to validate the domain for deep links on Google Play Console, and for that I need to ensure this URL is accessible:

```
https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

Every file that I have under `/public` on my app is reachable (e.g. `www.example.com/manifest.json`). So I created a folder .well-known under /public and put inside `assetlinks.json`.

However, I always get 404 on `https://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json`
The problem must be the `.well-known` folder, since it works well if I put the JSON directly under `/public`.

I tried adding a file `.nojekyll` on the root of my project, but still same issue.

Not sure if this is related, but I also have a logic like this, to display a fancy Not Found page when I enter a route that has not been previously defined.
<Route path="*" element={} />

So if I enter localhost:3000/asdf it correctly shows my fancy NotFound, but if I enter example.com/asdf it shows instead the GitHub Pages 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Adding `.nojekyll` to `/public` folder instead of the root folder (so that it is present in `/build` after running `npm run build`)
2. Change my deploy script on package.json to `"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build -t"` (I was missing `-t`)

Hope it helps other people!